# FluentValidation validation factory and Ninject DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, fluentvalidation

I'm using `NinjectHttpApplication` with couple modules defined in my project.

What I want is to create `FluentValidation` validation factory as described in http://www.thekip.nl/2011/09/22/using-fluentvalidation-for-both-domain-validation-and-validation-in-mvc-projects/.

To create a concrete validation factory I need to override

```
IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
```

method where I should then call

```
return kernel.Get<validatorType>() as IValidator
```

But I've read that using IKernel outside of `Global.asax` scope is not recommended.

What options are there to make what I want?

**EDIT: using Ninject-FluentValidation extension**

As Remo's stated there's an extension on `GitHub` (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc.fluentvalidation). There's a class in the extension:

```
public class NinjectValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase { ... }
```

which takes `IKernel` in constructor and creates instances of `IValidator`

```
public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
{
    if(((IList<IBinding>)Kernel.GetBindings(validatorType)).Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Kernel.Get(validatorType) as IValidator;
}
```

then my code goes like:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    private NinjectValidatorFactory nvfactory;

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());                        
    }
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }        
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(nvfactory));            
    }
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());            
        nvfactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

That works. I don't know could it be resolved better though. Also I don't understand the need to expose `IKernel` as a public property on `NinjectValidationFactory`.

Answer (score 10):

The Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation extension adds support for fluent validation to Ninject. It can be found on NuGet. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc.fluentvalidation

Comment: How to configure it? The Github readme wasn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I *highly* advise reading Mark Seemann's [*Dependency Injection in .NET*](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) book.

To keep it simple, if you're looking to ask the container for a dependency, you're not using Dependency Injection. You don't call the container. It'll call you.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. I show you a simple console app to demonstrate FluentValidation with NInject.

1. Create a console app in visual studio.
2. Intsall the nuget packages FluentValidation and NInject.

`Install-Package NInject`

`Install-Package FluentValidation`

3. Create the following classes.

   ```
   public class Customer
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Surname { get; set; }
       public string Forename { get; set; }
       public decimal Discount { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
   }

   using FluentValidation;
   public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
   {
       public CustomerValidator()
       {
           //RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotNull();
           RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotNull().NotEqual("foo");
       }
   }

   using FluentValidation;
   using Ninject;
   using System;

   public class NInjectValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
   {
       private readonly IKernel m_NInjectKernel;
       public NInjectValidatorFactory(IKernel kernel)
       {
           if (kernel == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("NInject kernel injected is null!!");

           m_NInjectKernel = kernel;
       }
       public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
       {
           return m_NInjectKernel.Get(validatorType) as IValidator;
       }
   }
   ```

   4.The main method inside the program class would be as follows.

   ```
   using FluentValidation;
   using Ninject;
   using System;
   using System.Linq;

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           // Set up the DI Container.
           var kernel = new StandardKernel();
           kernel.Bind<IValidator<Customer>>().To<CustomerValidator>().InSingletonScope();

           var nInjectvalidationFactory = kernel.Get<NInjectValidatorFactory>();
           var customer = kernel.Get<Customer>();

           var customerValidator = nInjectvalidationFactory.GetValidator<Customer>();

           var results = customerValidator.Validate(customer);

           if (!results.IsValid)
               results.Errors.ToList().ForEach(e =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorMessage);
                   Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode);
                   Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
                   Console.WriteLine(e.ResourceName);
                   Console.WriteLine(e.Severity);
               }
               );
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
   ```

   5. Just run this. The code is pretty self explanatory. Inside the main method, we are setting up the DI container, NInject in this case. Then we are doing the necessary bindings(mappings). Note only one mapping is required. That too as a singleton as explained [here](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/b.-Creating-a-Validator#a-note-on-performance) for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation of the kernel, this is not a problem as such.

It is not recommended, as it creates a dependency on the kernel (and as such you are using Service Location and not Dependency Injection).

Another option would be to use Ninjects notion of Providers as described by [Alexsander Beletsky](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/02/ninject-provider-as-factory-method.html).

Comment: Ok! That's a good article but could you explain howcome I apply this approach in context of my problem?